# RecyclerView - после удаления двух элементов из списка, а потом добавления их обратно, они накладываются друг на друга

Tags: java, android, recyclerview

Есть `RecyclerView`, находящийся внутри алертдиалога. В нулевой позиции расположен item со свичом. Если свич вкл., то надо показать ещё два элемента под ним, а если выкл., то убрать эти элементы.

Беда в том, что если убрать элементы из списка, а потом снова добавить, то появляются их версии, которые были до удаления + свежедобавленные элементы прямо поверх них.

Все вьюшки создаются программно, без XML.

Вот код:

```
if (position == 0) {
                    MaterialSwitch switcher = DialogUtil.getRecyclerView().getLayoutManager().findViewByPosition(0).findViewWithTag("switch");

                    if (switcher.isChecked()) {

                        items.add(1, new RecyclerViewItem(RecyclerViewItem.OPTION_SNOOZE_SETTINGS_DURATION, getString(R.string.snooze_duration), 10, 5, 45, new LabelFormatter() {
                            @NonNull
                            @Override
                            public String getFormattedValue(float value) {
                                return getResources().getQuantityString(R.plurals.minutes, (int) value, (int) value);
                            }
                        }, true));
                        items.add(2, new RecyclerViewItem(RecyclerViewItem.OPTION_SNOOZE_SETTINGS_MAX_COUNT, getString(R.string.max_snoozes), 1, 1, 11, new LabelFormatter() {
                            @NonNull
                            @Override
                            public String getFormattedValue(float value) {

                                if (value != 11.0) {
                                    return getResources().getQuantityString(R.plurals.times, (int) value, (int) value);
                                } else {
                                    return getString(R.string.unlimited);
                                }
                            }
                        }, true));

                        DialogUtil.getRecyclerView().getAdapter().notifyItemRangeInserted(1, 2);
                    } else {
                        items.remove(2);
                        items.remove(1);

                        DialogUtil.getRecyclerView().getAdapter().notifyItemRangeRemoved(1, 2);
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Так, ладно, решение я нашёл - добавил в ветку else условия `switcher.isChecked()` код удаения всех вьюшек из корневого лэйатуа item'a:
`

```
 //Сначала удалим View из item'ов
                        ConstraintLayout layout1 = DialogUtil.getRecyclerView().getLayoutManager().findViewByPosition(1).findViewWithTag("rootLayout");
                        ConstraintLayout layout2 = DialogUtil.getRecyclerView().getLayoutManager().findViewByPosition(2).findViewWithTag("rootLayout");

                        layout1.removeAllViews();
                        layout2.removeAllViews();
```

Но мне всё равно не понятно, почему эти вьюшки остались, а не удалились после `Adapter::notifyItemRangeRemoved()`

Answer (score 0):

Не нужно пытаться удалять элементы из списка по индексу через removeAllViews(). Попробуйте более детально узнать как работает RecyclerView, в частности адаптер. Адаптер принимает список элементов (в вашем случаи это айтемы со свитчами). Чтобы удалить какой-то из этих элементов просто предоставьте адаптеру новый список без этого элемента и вызывайте `notifyDataSetChanged()`. Так же вы говорили, что свитч у вас влияет на внешний вид айтема. Эту логику можно реализовать во ViewHolder, например если `switcher.isChecked()` просто сделайте `view.show()` или `view.gone()`. Тоесть те самые два элемента, которые показываются по свитчу пускай будут чайлдами конкретного айтема из списка.